# Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS X540L: No WiFi adapter found and no network controller found

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, asus, lspci

In `Settings->Wi-Fi`, my system states that no Wi-Fi adapter is found. When I boot into Windows, WiFi is not working either.

My computer is an ASUS X540L.

### When this started happening

---

I was trying to get HDMI output to show the screen on my laptop and not act as a second screen. I changed some display settings and restarted. When the computer was restarting, the terminal fell into some sort of loop with the same two or three output strings occuring. I held the power button to escape that after a few minutes. This occured when I was running Ubuntu version `17.x`, and I upgraded to `18.04` a few hours ago hoping this issue would go away.

### Debug info

---

The output from the target file after executing

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info
```

is as follows:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Sep 2018 14:17 EDT -0400

Booted last: 30 Sep 2018 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b52b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13d3:3423 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ath3k                  20480  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
bluetooth             548864  34 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,ath3k,btusb
wmi                    24576  2 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  45056  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0f2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e::3  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e:305a:eb16:cde:3067  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e:f24:7661:b458:c8d8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd00:1cab:c072:b9e2:e4d2:7b68:2ede:6441  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3780:5763:a91:5093  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00:1cab:c072:b9e2:305a:eb16:cde:3067  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28007  bytes 23756386 (23.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23613  bytes 4176305 (4.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 604  bytes 49132 (49.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 604  bytes 49132 (49.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0f2  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0f2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0f2
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0f2

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search hitronhub.home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       848     1  0 14:05 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0f2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.2/net/enp2s0f2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0f2
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5f0b86f9-0c09-38f5-a77c-dd96b407d92c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.17/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          hitronhub.home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        host_name = david-X540LJ
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.17
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       expiry = 1538936004
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name = hitronhub.home
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2607:fea8:5ac0:129e::3/128
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2607:fea8:5ac0:129e:305a:eb16:cde:3067/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fd00:1cab:c072:b9e2:305a:eb16:cde:3067/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         2607:fea8:5ac0:129e:f24:7661:b458:c8d8/64
IP6.ADDRESS[5]:                         fd00:1cab:c072:b9e2:e4d2:7b68:2ede:6441/64
IP6.ADDRESS[6]:                         fe80::3780:5763:a91:5093/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1eab:c0ff:fe72:b9e2
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fc00::/7, nh = fe80::1eab:c0ff:fe72:b9e2, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fd00:1cab:c072:b9e2::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e::/64, nh = fe80::1eab:c0ff:fe72:b9e2, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::1eab:c0ff:fe72:b9e2, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[6]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[7]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[8]:                           dst = 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[9]:                           dst = 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e::3/128, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2607:fea8:5ac0:129e:1eab:c0ff:fe72:b9e2
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:8d:61:97:d5:f3:58:16:4d:65:94:9:95:ed:12:ed:89
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e:1eab:c0ff:fe72:b9e2
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        rebind = 96228
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        max_life = 548859
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        preferred_life = 120289
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[8]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[9]:                        life_starts = 1538317655
DHCP6.OPTION[10]:                       ip6_address = 2607:fea8:5ac0:129e::3
DHCP6.OPTION[11]:                       ip6_prefixlen = 64
DHCP6.OPTION[12]:                       renew = 60144
DHCP6.OPTION[13]:                       iaid = f6:71:89:95
DHCP6.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:23:40:e7:f4:1c:ab:c0:72:b9:e2
DHCP6.OPTION[15]:                       starts = 1538317655
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{10}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5f0b86f9-0c09-38f5-a77c-dd96b407d92c | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=AndroidAP
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam]] (600 root)
[connection] id=eduroam | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=eduroam
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/360Dev]] (600 root)
[connection] id=360Dev | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=360Dev
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Fergus_House_Wi-Fi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Fergus_House_Wi-Fi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Fergus_House_Wi-Fi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SantaClaus]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SantaClaus | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SantaClaus
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XPLORNET]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XPLORNET | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=XPLORNET
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FergusHouse_Temp]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FergusHouse_Temp | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=FergusHouse_Temp
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Cloudwifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Cloudwifi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=74:C6:3B:82:3A:79 | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Cloudwifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/harrington1504]] (600 root)
[connection] id=harrington1504 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=harrington1504
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Toronto (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0f2  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0f2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     36C0F7AEF3B569F1798216D
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath3k
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf]
options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  472.357605] usb 1-4: device firmware changed
[  804.972063] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7276:8a669024

########## wireless info END ############
```

Here is the output from `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1603] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9c90] (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:9c94] (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:9c96] (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9c98] (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc3] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller [8086:9ca4] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5286 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5286] (rev 01)
02:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 06)
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] [10de:1299] (rev a1)
```

`sudo rfkill list` gives the following:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

I've tried reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` and have been attempting to fix my issue with no success. How can I get Wi-Fi working again? I jumped into BIOS, but, from what I saw, there wasn't an option to enable/disable wireless connections, and there wasn't anything set to `Lock` which seemed to be linked to wireless connections.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If wifi doesn't work in Windows how is it ever going to work in Ubuntu?  I would say the wifi is broken and you should replace it.  I don't see the logic installing bcmwl-kernel-source or the iwlwifi backports to fix an issue with an Atheros wifi device

Comment: Jeremy, what do you mean by "it"?

Comment: Wifi, I think your wifi is dead